# How to show all data of jqgrid datatable by selecting All option?

Tags: java, jquery, jqgrid

I am using JQuery Datatable to show data into grid.when i am trying to access all the data by selecting all option..i am getting one error every time.

### Data Table code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#generalreport").dataTable({

                "bServerSide": true,
                "sScrollY": "370px",
                "sAjaxSource": "ajaxSearchGeneralReport.action",
                "bProcessing": true,

              "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "bLengthChange": true,
                "iDisplayLength" : -1,
                "aLengthMenu": [[50,100,300,-1],[50,100,300,'All']],

                 "sDom": 'T<"clear"><"H"lfr>t<"F"ip>',
                "oTableTools": {
                  "sSwfPath": "media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
                }     
            });
        });
```

### Error

```
ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: fromIndex(0) > toIndex(-1)
    at java.util.SubList.<init>(AbstractList.java:604)
    at java.util.AbstractList.subList(AbstractList.java:468)
    at x.y.z.action.GeneralReportAction.execute(GeneralReportAction.java:119)
```

Comment: Where does your code says the issue is in jqgrid, even you have not posted the jqgrid code here?

Comment: hi Jai,issue is not in jqgrid,its in JQuery Datatables,i am trying to fetch all data,but ALL is not working,onclicking ALL its showing this error.